# Error when trying to creating a StateFulSet: 0/9 nodes are available: 9 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, kubernetes-statefulset

I am trying to replace a deployment with StateFulSet having a persistent volume.

**A quick summary:**

1. The deployment was ran successfully for a web app having front end and backend (MySQL)
2. Then we deleted the deployment.
3. Wrote down the YAML file for Statefulset w.r.t backend.
4. applied the statefulset YAML.
5. However, the pod for MySQL does not come up and always goes into '*CrashLoopBackOff*' state.

Request your help to understand the issue.

I am putting all the logs below - it is lengthy but hopefully it will help to better understand the entire scenario.

- **Original config:**

```
~] $ kubectl get all 
NAME                                  READY   STATUS    RESTARTS      AGE
pod/gowebapp-54f6cd5f64-6xl99         1/1     Running   0             73s
pod/gowebapp-54f6cd5f64-fn6sc         1/1     Running   3 (83s ago)   2m8s
pod/gowebapp-mysql-7c4ddfccdf-2x27f   1/1     Running   0             107s

NAME                     TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
service/gowebapp         ClusterIP   100.xx.xxx.xxx   <none>        8080/TCP   2m8s
service/gowebapp-mysql   ClusterIP   100.xx.xx.xx     <none>        3306/TCP   2m30s

NAME                             READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/gowebapp         2/2     2            2           2m20s
deployment.apps/gowebapp-mysql   1/1     1            1           2m30s

NAME                                        DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/gowebapp-54f6cd5f64         2         2         2       2m8s
replicaset.apps/gowebapp-5744cdff7d         0         0         0       2m20s
replicaset.apps/gowebapp-mysql-6b685888cd   0         0         0       2m30s
replicaset.apps/gowebapp-mysql-7c4ddfccdf   1         1         1       107s
[~] $
```

- **Aim of the exercise:** To replace the deployment with StatefulSet having a persistent volume.

```
*Step 1: Delete the existing deployment for MySQL.*

[~] $ kubectl delete deployment gowebapp-mysql
deployment.apps "gowebapp-mysql" deleted


*Step 2: check the deployment no longer exists and hence the pod is terminated as well. *

[~] $ kubectl get all 
NAME                                  READY   STATUS        RESTARTS        AGE
pod/gowebapp-54f6cd5f64-6xl99         1/1     Running       0               3m29s
pod/gowebapp-54f6cd5f64-fn6sc         1/1     Running       3 (3m39s ago)   4m24s
pod/gowebapp-mysql-7c4ddfccdf-2x27f   1/1     Terminating   0               4m3s

NAME                     TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
service/gowebapp         ClusterIP   100.xx.xxx.xxx   <none>        8080/TCP   4m24s
service/gowebapp-mysql   ClusterIP   100.xx.xx.xx     <none>        3306/TCP   4m46s

NAME                       READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/gowebapp   2/2     2            2           4m36s

NAME                                  DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/gowebapp-54f6cd5f64   2         2         2       4m24s
replicaset.apps/gowebapp-5744cdff7d   0         0         0       4m36s
[~] $ 


*step 3: check the files in the working directory. Create the StatefulSet file.*

[~/gowebapp/gowebapp-mysql] $ ls -lrt
total 20
-rw-r--r-- 1 ABC!@# root 2619 Oct 24 20:24 gowebapp.sql
-rw-r--r-- 1 ABC!@# root   73 Jan  5 10:53 Dockerfile
-rw-r--r-- 1 ABC!@# root  238 Jan  5 10:54 gowebapp-mysql-service.yaml
-rw-r--r-- 1 ABC!@# root  631 Jan  5 10:54 gowebapp-mysql-deployment-lab02.yaml
-rw-r--r-- 1 ABC!@# root 1021 Jan  5 10:54 gowebapp-mysql-deployment.yaml
[~/gowebapp/gowebapp-mysql] $ 
[~/gowebapp/gowebapp-mysql] $ vi pv.yaml
[~/gowebapp/gowebapp-mysql] $ 
[~/gowebapp/gowebapp-mysql] $ cat pv.yaml
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv01
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: /var/pv/pv01
```

[~/gowebapp/gowebapp-mysql] $ cat gowebapp-mysql-sts.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata: 
  name: gowebapp-mysql
  labels:
    app: gowebapp-mysql
    tier: backend
spec:
  serviceName: gowebapp-mysql
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: gowebapp-mysql
      tier: backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: gowebapp-mysql
        tier: backend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: gowebapp-mysql
        env:
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: mypassword
        image: $REGISTRY_HOST/gowebapp-mysql:v1  *==> removing entire path on purpose*
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
        livenessProbe:
          tcpSocket:
            port: 3306
          initialDelaySeconds: 20
          periodSeconds: 5
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        readinessProbe:
          exec:
            command: ["mysql", "-uroot", "-XXXXXXXXXXXX", "-e", "use gowebapp; select count(*) from user"]
          initialDelaySeconds: 25
          periodSeconds: 10
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        volumeMounts:
        - name: mysql-pv
          mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: mysql-pv
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 5Gi
```

```
*Step 4: apply the StatefulSet YAML file*

[~/gowebapp/gowebapp-mysql] $ kubectl apply -f gowebapp-mysql-sts.yaml
statefulset.apps/gowebapp-mysql created



*Step 5: check the configuration again. We observe the MySQL pod is in error. *

[~/gowebapp/gowebapp-mysql] $ kubectl get all 
NAME                            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS      AGE
pod/gowebapp-54f6cd5f64-6xl99   1/1     Running   0             12m
pod/gowebapp-54f6cd5f64-fn6sc   1/1     Running   3 (12m ago)   13m
pod/gowebapp-mysql-0            0/1     Error     1 (2s ago)    19s

NAME                     TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
service/gowebapp         ClusterIP   100.xx.xxx.xxx   <none>        8080/TCP   13m
service/gowebapp-mysql   ClusterIP   100.xx.xx.xx     <none>        3306/TCP   13m

NAME                       READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/gowebapp   2/2     2            2           13m

NAME                                  DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/gowebapp-54f6cd5f64   2         2         2       13m
replicaset.apps/gowebapp-5744cdff7d   0         0         0       13m

NAME                              READY   AGE
statefulset.apps/gowebapp-mysql   0/1     19s
[~/gowebapp/gowebapp-mysql] $ 



*Step 6: describe the MySQL pod which is in error to see the configuration and event logs.*

[~/gowebapp/gowebapp-mysql] $ kubectl describe pod gowebapp-mysql-0 
Name:         gowebapp-mysql-0
Namespace:    eduk8s-labs-w19-s024
Priority:     0
Node:         ip-10-0-4-209.ec2.internal/10.0.4.209
Start Time:   Thu, 05 Jan 2023 11:07:26 +0000
Labels:       app=gowebapp-mysql
              controller-revision-hash=gowebapp-mysql-9bbb68b64
              statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name=gowebapp-mysql-0
              tier=backend
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Running
IP:           100.x.x.x
IPs:
  IP:           100.x.x.x
Controlled By:  StatefulSet/gowebapp-mysql
Containers:
  gowebapp-mysql:
    Container ID:   containerd://464cfecbee1dccfb28e25adf1f12a2264ed44e30854b15ed25e5f69897e1aa15
    Image:          XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/gowebapp-mysql:v1
    Image ID:       XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/gowebapp-mysql@sha256:991935ad6c0c2b7e4ba7acdae920499d0a295ae29546277b42c0794efe9a95bf
    Port:           3306/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
   ** State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated**
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    141
      Started:      Thu, 05 Jan 2023 11:08:00 +0000
      Finished:     Thu, 05 Jan 2023 11:08:00 +0000
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  2
    Liveness:       tcp-socket :3306 delay=20s timeout=1s period=5s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:      exec [mysql -uroot -XXXXXXX -e use gowebapp; select count(*) from user] delay=25s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:  XXXXXX
    Mounts:
      /var/lib/mysql from mysql-pv (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-kz5ds (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  mysql-pv:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  mysql-pv-gowebapp-mysql-0
    ReadOnly:   false
  kube-api-access-kz5ds:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason                  Age                From                     Message
  ----     ------                  ----               ----                     -------
  **Warning  FailedScheduling        58s                default-scheduler        0/9 nodes are available: 9 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims.
  Warning  FailedScheduling        55s                default-scheduler        0/9 nodes are available: 9 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims.**
  Normal   Scheduled               53s                default-scheduler        Successfully assigned eduk8s-labs-w19-s024/gowebapp-mysql-0 to ip-10-0-4-209.ec2.internal
  Normal   SuccessfulAttachVolume  51s                attachdetach-controller  AttachVolume.Attach succeeded for volume "pvc-6a8f5389-dd8a-4416-a704-8805fc6c8fc2"
  Normal   Pulling                 44s                kubelet                  Pulling image "XXXXXXXX/gowebapp-mysql:v1"
  Normal   Pulled                  42s                kubelet                  Successfully pulled image "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX/gowebapp-mysql:v1" in 1.33039215s
  Normal   Created                 19s (x3 over 42s)  kubelet                  Created container gowebapp-mysql
  Normal   Started                 19s (x3 over 42s)  kubelet                  Started container gowebapp-mysql
  Normal   Pulled                  19s (x2 over 41s)  kubelet                  Container image "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/gowebapp-mysql:v1" already present on machine
  Warning  BackOff                 14s (x7 over 40s)  kubelet                  Back-off restarting failed container
[~/gowebapp/gowebapp-mysql] $
```

```
*step 7: check that PVC exists - which it does.*

[~/gowebapp/gowebapp-mysql] $ kubectl get pvc
NAME                        STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
mysql-pv-gowebapp-mysql-0   Bound    pvc-6a8f5389-dd8a-4416-a704-8805fc6c8fc2   5Gi        RWO            default        104s
[~/gowebapp/gowebapp-mysql] $ 
[~/gowebapp/gowebapp-mysql] $ 
[~/gowebapp/gowebapp-mysql] $ kubectl describe persistentvolumeclaims mysql-pv-gowebapp-mysql-0 
Name:          mysql-pv-gowebapp-mysql-0
Namespace:     eduk8s-labs-w19-s024
StorageClass:  default
Status:        Bound
Volume:        pvc-6a8f5389-dd8a-4416-a704-8805fc6c8fc2
Labels:        app=gowebapp-mysql
               tier=backend
Annotations:   pv.kubernetes.io/bind-completed: yes
               pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: yes
               volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner: ebs.csi.aws.com
               volume.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner: ebs.csi.aws.com
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:      5Gi
Access Modes:  RWO
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Used By:       gowebapp-mysql-0
Events:
  Type    Reason                 Age                  From                                                                                      Message
  ----    ------                 ----                 ----                                                                                      -------
  Normal  ExternalProvisioning   117s (x2 over 117s)  persistentvolume-controller                                                               waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "ebs.csi.aws.com" or manually created by system administrator
  Normal  Provisioning           117s                 ebs.csi.aws.com_ebs-csi-controller-75ddf66bf8-fw4ww_f01348ce-0cd7-4464-a3c9-49c87925167d  External provisioner is provisioning volume for claim "eduk8s-labs-w19-s024/mysql-pv-gowebapp-mysql-0"
  Normal  ProvisioningSucceeded  114s                 ebs.csi.aws.com_ebs-csi-controller-75ddf66bf8-fw4ww_f01348ce-0cd7-4464-a3c9-49c87925167d  Successfully provisioned volume pvc-6a8f5389-dd8a-4416-a704-8805fc6c8fc2
[~/gowebapp/gowebapp-mysql] $ 



*Step 8: again, we check the configuration to see that MySQL Pod is in 'CrashLoopBackOff'*

[~/gowebapp/gowebapp-mysql] $ kubectl get all 
NAME                            READY   STATUS             RESTARTS      AGE
pod/gowebapp-54f6cd5f64-6xl99   1/1     Running            0             14m
pod/gowebapp-54f6cd5f64-fn6sc   1/1     Running            3 (14m ago)   15m
pod/gowebapp-mysql-0            0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   4 (18s ago)   2m18s

NAME                     TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
service/gowebapp         ClusterIP   100.xx.xxx.xxx   <none>        8080/TCP   15m
service/gowebapp-mysql   ClusterIP   100.xx.xx.xx     <none>        3306/TCP   15m

NAME                       READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/gowebapp   2/2     2            2           15m

NAME                                  DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/gowebapp-54f6cd5f64   2         2         2       15m
replicaset.apps/gowebapp-5744cdff7d   0         0         0       15m

NAME                              READY   AGE
statefulset.apps/gowebapp-mysql   0/1     2m18s
[~/gowebapp/gowebapp-mysql] $
```

```
- **complete set of logs:** 
note: removed the entire path for registry and purposefully replaced with XXXXXXXX.

[~/gowebapp/gowebapp-mysql] $ kubectl get events
LAST SEEN   TYPE      REASON                   OBJECT                                            MESSAGE
14m         Normal    Scheduled                pod/gowebapp-54f6cd5f64-6xl99                     Successfully assigned eduk8s-labs-w19-s024/gowebapp-54f6cd5f64-6xl99 to ip-10-0-0-47.ec2.internal
14m         Normal    Pulled                   pod/gowebapp-54f6cd5f64-6xl99                     Container image "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/gowebapp:v1" already present on machine
14m         Normal    Created                  pod/gowebapp-54f6cd5f64-6xl99                     Created container gowebapp
14m         Normal    Started                  pod/gowebapp-54f6cd5f64-6xl99                     Started container gowebapp
15m         Normal    Scheduled                pod/gowebapp-54f6cd5f64-fn6sc                     Successfully assigned eduk8s-labs-w19-s024/gowebapp-54f6cd5f64-fn6sc to ip-10-0-4-38.ec2.internal
15m         Normal    Pulled                   pod/gowebapp-54f6cd5f64-fn6sc                     Container image "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/gowebapp:v1" already present on machine
15m         Normal    Created                  pod/gowebapp-54f6cd5f64-fn6sc                     Created container gowebapp
15m         Normal    Started                  pod/gowebapp-54f6cd5f64-fn6sc                     Started container gowebapp
15m         Warning   Unhealthy                pod/gowebapp-54f6cd5f64-fn6sc                     Readiness probe failed: Get "http://100.96.2.240:8080/": dial tcp 100.96.2.240:8080: connect: connection refused
15m         Warning   Unhealthy                pod/gowebapp-54f6cd5f64-fn6sc                     Liveness probe failed: dial tcp 100.96.2.240:8080: connect: connection refused
15m         Normal    Killing                  pod/gowebapp-54f6cd5f64-fn6sc                     Container gowebapp failed liveness probe, will be restarted
15m         Normal    SuccessfulCreate         replicaset/gowebapp-54f6cd5f64                    Created pod: gowebapp-54f6cd5f64-fn6sc
14m         Normal    SuccessfulCreate         replicaset/gowebapp-54f6cd5f64                    Created pod: gowebapp-54f6cd5f64-6xl99
16m         Normal    Scheduled                pod/gowebapp-5744cdff7d-bfvdl                     Successfully assigned eduk8s-labs-w19-s024/gowebapp-5744cdff7d-bfvdl to ip-10-0-0-47.ec2.internal
16m         Normal    Pulling                  pod/gowebapp-5744cdff7d-bfvdl                     Pulling image "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/gowebapp:v1"
15m         Normal    Pulled                   pod/gowebapp-5744cdff7d-bfvdl                     Successfully pulled image "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/gowebapp:v1" in 2.293354548s
15m         Normal    Created                  pod/gowebapp-5744cdff7d-bfvdl                     Created container gowebapp
15m         Normal    Started                  pod/gowebapp-5744cdff7d-bfvdl                     Started container gowebapp
14m         Normal    Killing                  pod/gowebapp-5744cdff7d-bfvdl                     Stopping container gowebapp
16m         Normal    Scheduled                pod/gowebapp-5744cdff7d-ccc45                     Successfully assigned eduk8s-labs-w19-s024/gowebapp-5744cdff7d-ccc45 to ip-10-0-4-38.ec2.internal
16m         Normal    Pulling                  pod/gowebapp-5744cdff7d-ccc45                     Pulling image "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/gowebapp:v1"
15m         Normal    Pulled                   pod/gowebapp-5744cdff7d-ccc45                     Successfully pulled image "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/gowebapp:v1" in 2.232486921s
15m         Normal    Created                  pod/gowebapp-5744cdff7d-ccc45                     Created container gowebapp
15m         Normal    Started                  pod/gowebapp-5744cdff7d-ccc45                     Started container gowebapp
14m         Normal    Killing                  pod/gowebapp-5744cdff7d-ccc45                     Stopping container gowebapp
16m         Normal    SuccessfulCreate         replicaset/gowebapp-5744cdff7d                    Created pod: gowebapp-5744cdff7d-ccc45
16m         Normal    SuccessfulCreate         replicaset/gowebapp-5744cdff7d                    Created pod: gowebapp-5744cdff7d-bfvdl
14m         Normal    SuccessfulDelete         replicaset/gowebapp-5744cdff7d                    Deleted pod: gowebapp-5744cdff7d-ccc45
14m         Normal    SuccessfulDelete         replicaset/gowebapp-5744cdff7d                    Deleted pod: gowebapp-5744cdff7d-bfvdl
*2m58s       Warning   FailedScheduling         pod/gowebapp-mysql-0                              0/9 nodes are available: 9 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims.
2m55s       Warning   FailedScheduling         pod/gowebapp-mysql-0                              0/9 nodes are available: 9 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims.
2m53s       Normal    Scheduled                pod/gowebapp-mysql-0                              Successfully assigned eduk8s-labs-w19-s024/gowebapp-mysql-0 to ip-10-0-4-209.ec2.internal
2m51s       Normal    SuccessfulAttachVolume   pod/gowebapp-mysql-0                              AttachVolume.Attach succeeded for volume "pvc-6a8f5389-dd8a-4416-a704-8805fc6c8fc2"
2m44s       Normal    Pulling                  pod/gowebapp-mysql-0                              Pulling image "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/gowebapp-mysql:v1"
2m42s       Normal    Pulled                   pod/gowebapp-mysql-0                              Successfully pulled image "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/gowebapp-mysql:v1" in 1.33039215s
106s        Normal    Created                  pod/gowebapp-mysql-0                              Created container gowebapp-mysql
106s        Normal    Started                  pod/gowebapp-mysql-0                              Started container gowebapp-mysql
106s        Normal    Pulled                   pod/gowebapp-mysql-0                              Container image "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/gowebapp-mysql:v1" already present on machine
88s         Warning   BackOff                  pod/gowebapp-mysql-0                              Back-off restarting failed container*
16m         Normal    Scheduled                pod/gowebapp-mysql-6b685888cd-vmbbt               Successfully assigned eduk8s-labs-w19-s024/gowebapp-mysql-6b685888cd-vmbbt to ip-10-0-2-110.ec2.internal
16m         Normal    Pulling                  pod/gowebapp-mysql-6b685888cd-vmbbt               Pulling image "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/gowebapp-mysql:v1"
16m         Normal    Pulled                   pod/gowebapp-mysql-6b685888cd-vmbbt               Successfully pulled image "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/gowebapp-mysql:v1" in 1.353941669s
16m         Normal    Created                  pod/gowebapp-mysql-6b685888cd-vmbbt               Created container gowebapp-mysql
16m         Normal    Started                  pod/gowebapp-mysql-6b685888cd-vmbbt               Started container gowebapp-mysql
16m         Normal    Killing                  pod/gowebapp-mysql-6b685888cd-vmbbt               Stopping container gowebapp-mysql
16m         Normal    SuccessfulCreate         replicaset/gowebapp-mysql-6b685888cd              Created pod: gowebapp-mysql-6b685888cd-vmbbt
16m         Normal    SuccessfulDelete         replicaset/gowebapp-mysql-6b685888cd              Deleted pod: gowebapp-mysql-6b685888cd-vmbbt
15m         Normal    Scheduled                pod/gowebapp-mysql-7c4ddfccdf-2x27f               Successfully assigned eduk8s-labs-w19-s024/gowebapp-mysql-7c4ddfccdf-2x27f to ip-10-0-2-110.ec2.internal
15m         Normal    Pulled                   pod/gowebapp-mysql-7c4ddfccdf-2x27f               Container image "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/gowebapp-mysql:v1" already present on machine
15m         Normal    Created                  pod/gowebapp-mysql-7c4ddfccdf-2x27f               Created container gowebapp-mysql
15m         Normal    Started                  pod/gowebapp-mysql-7c4ddfccdf-2x27f               Started container gowebapp-mysql
11m         Normal    Killing                  pod/gowebapp-mysql-7c4ddfccdf-2x27f               Stopping container gowebapp-mysql
11m         Warning   Unhealthy                pod/gowebapp-mysql-7c4ddfccdf-2x27f               Readiness probe failed: Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure....
15m         Normal    SuccessfulCreate         replicaset/gowebapp-mysql-7c4ddfccdf              Created pod: gowebapp-mysql-7c4ddfccdf-2x27f
16m         Normal    ScalingReplicaSet        deployment/gowebapp-mysql                         Scaled up replica set gowebapp-mysql-6b685888cd to 1
16m         Normal    ScalingReplicaSet        deployment/gowebapp-mysql                         Scaled down replica set gowebapp-mysql-6b685888cd to 0
15m         Normal    ScalingReplicaSet        deployment/gowebapp-mysql                         Scaled up replica set gowebapp-mysql-7c4ddfccdf to 1
2m59s       Normal    SuccessfulCreate         statefulset/gowebapp-mysql                        create Claim mysql-pv-gowebapp-mysql-0 Pod gowebapp-mysql-0 in StatefulSet gowebapp-mysql success
2m59s       Normal    SuccessfulCreate         statefulset/gowebapp-mysql                        create Pod gowebapp-mysql-0 in StatefulSet gowebapp-mysql successful
16m         Normal    ScalingReplicaSet        deployment/gowebapp                               Scaled up replica set gowebapp-5744cdff7d to 2
15m         Normal    ScalingReplicaSet        deployment/gowebapp                               Scaled up replica set gowebapp-54f6cd5f64 to 1
14m         Normal    ScalingReplicaSet        deployment/gowebapp                               Scaled down replica set gowebapp-5744cdff7d to 1
14m         Normal    ScalingReplicaSet        deployment/gowebapp                               Scaled up replica set gowebapp-54f6cd5f64 to 2
14m         Normal    ScalingReplicaSet        deployment/gowebapp                               Scaled down replica set gowebapp-5744cdff7d to 0
2m59s       Normal    ExternalProvisioning     persistentvolumeclaim/mysql-pv-gowebapp-mysql-0   waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "ebs.csi.aws.com" or manually created by system administrator
2m59s       Normal    Provisioning             persistentvolumeclaim/mysql-pv-gowebapp-mysql-0   External provisioner is provisioning volume for claim "eduk8s-labs-w19-s024/mysql-pv-gowebapp-mysql-0"
2m56s       Normal    ProvisioningSucceeded    persistentvolumeclaim/mysql-pv-gowebapp-mysql-0   Successfully provisioned volume pvc-6a8f5389-dd8a-4416-a704-8805fc6c8fc2
[
```

~/gowebapp/gowebapp-mysql] $

Tried to check the logs and other Stack overflow questions for similar error messages but did not help.

The expectation is to setup the StateFulSet succcessfully such that the MySql has a persistent storage and not ephemeral.